# Android: modeling a sliding view using interfaces and inheritance

Tags: java, android, inheritance, interface

I'm trying to write a generic view (called `SlidingView`), that tracks sliding gestures, and updates its position accordingly.

The "sliding" behavior is independent on the particular type of View (text, image, etc). So I would like to write this behavior in an abstract class (since I cannot add behavior to an interface). The problem is that if I define such a `SlidingView` class, I cannot instantiate it with any other subclass of a view (since then I'll be inheriting from multiple classes).

What is a possible way of solving this or to model the problem in a better way?

Comment: Create a called `helper` class. This probably could be a `View.OnTouchListener` that tracks all the movement, inertia, positioning, and implementing views simply pass callbacks to it.

Comment: I guess this is what I would end up doing. If I had to model this, I'd put the behavior in the view itself. But having into account the fact that Java does not support multiple inheritance I guess this is the best way around...